# .exe doesn't run on other computers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I've written a small C# program (Forms) in Visual Studio 15 that needs to be tested on other computers, but it doesn't even seem to start and my biggest problem is that I'm not getting any error messages. So far I've tried

- Debug and release
- The publish tool (ClickOnce or similar)
- Switching .NET version (in range 4 to 4.6)
- Installing newer .NET versions on the target computers
- Removing and adding references back again
- Targeting 32 and **64 bit** < *I thought I did this, but apparently not.*

but all that happens is that the process shows up in the Task Manager for a short period of time before disappearing again, leaving no error message what so ever.

Would you have any idea how to track this problem down?

**Edit:**

Thanks for making me aware of event viewer. Now I have errors:

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException
Stack: 
  at MyApp.Form1..ctor()
  at MyApp.Program.Main()
```

and

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.Exe, version: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x577bb57c
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18264, timestamp: 0x56e1b34d
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00015b68
Faulting process id: 0x1128
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1d6c4a0d4331f
Faulting application path: *path to exe*
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: df7b19f4-42b7-11e6-8271-00133b0f5ac0
Faulting package name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Edit 2:** *for anyone coming here looking for answers*

I had to build it with Platform as 64 bit in Configuration Manager to work, as one of my references was dependent on that.

Comment: Any errors on event viewer?

Comment: Does it use any files or databases?

Comment: Ah, yes, I wasn't aware of event viewer. Updating question, though I might be able to find the answer online.

Comment: 32/64 bit problem?

Comment: Some Ideas: Checking your program with Depends.exe to view missing references, or checking for all windows updates... sometime it helps.

Comment: Damn right @gsharp. It runs fine when setting "Platform" to x64. Apparently I did only try 32 bit before. Thanks!